# Flutter: I just want to play a sound! (July 2021/audioplayers/working on emulator, no sound on physical android device)

Tags: flutter

I just want to play a sound on my Android device.

After editing the **android/build.gradle** file and figuring out that for some reason the audioplayers package thinks that all file-paths begin with a silent 'assets/', I got an example that works!

But...  It only works on my android emulator, if I use a physical Android device:
no sound, but the debug log chirps along the same as it did on emulator.

Any suggestions?  Code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() => runApp(MartinApp());

class MartinApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MartinAppState createState() => _MartinAppState();
}

class _MartinAppState extends State<MartinApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => player.play('55.mp3', volume: 1),
                  child: Text('press here'))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```